# Facebook login in iOS application with python backend authentication.

Tags: python, ios, swift, facebook-login

I had created an iOS application with Facebook login. Whenever I opened up my application it shows the login view again and again. I want to open a main view if the user once entered the credentials of his/her Facebook account. I am using python as my backend, if anyone could help me.

Comment: where you struck bro....

Comment: I didn't started yet I want knowledge how to talk my login page with the backend, and automatically loads the first view. How to implement in python. Give me some reference. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: And yes i completed the login page in iOS getting succesfully logged in but when i run my app again it shows the login page.@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: simple bro use nsuserdefault for your concept , do you need the code..

Comment: yeah that would be helpful to me and Thanx.@Anbu.Karthik